# Connect I2C bus,i2cset: write failed: Connection timed out

Tags: linux, testing, embedded, yocto, i2c

Hey all i am using sama5d27-som1-ek board and trying to access I2C bus but facing problem please help me to solve the problem.
1)i2cdetect 0

```
root@sama5d27-som1-ek-sd:~# i2cdetect 0
i2cdetect: WARNING! This program can confuse your I2C bus
Continue? [y/N] y
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 2a -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: 40 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 5c -- -- --
60: 60 -- -- -- 64 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: 70 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
root@sama5d27-som1-ek-sd:~#
```

when i use i2cset command it show connection time out

```
root@sama5d27-som1-ek-sd:~# i2cset 0  0x2a 01 0x08
i2cset: WARNING! This program can confuse your I2C bus
Continue? [y/N] y
i2cset: write failed: Connection timed out
root@sama5d27-som1-ek-sd:~#
```

can any one suggest me what is error.

Comment: Without more information it's hard to tell. Might be electrical properties are not okay for chosen frequency, might be frequency itself is not correct for all devices (hint: start from 100kHz for all). Might be driver issue, or simple your code is not correct (read datasheet).

Comment: Thank you ,i am just using inbuilt function of busybox.to check i2c connection.can you suggest any think i can be  test i2c

Comment: Yes, it's called oscilloscope.